# Ocultar div padre cuando deja de tener hijos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un div padre que contiene varios hijos que aparecen y reaparecen. Me gustaría hacer desaparecer al padre cuando éste se queda sin hijos.

```js
$("#ocul1").click(function(){
  $("#hijo1").toggle();
});


$("#ocul2").click(function(){
  $("#hijo2").toggle();
});

$("#ocul3").click(function(){
  $("#hijo3").toggle();
});
```

```css
#padre1 {
  background-color:red;
  width:30%;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre1">
  DivPadre1 
    <br>
    <br>
<div id="hijo1">
  DivHijo1 <button id="ocul1">x</button>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo2">
  DivHijo2 <button id="ocul2">x</button>
  </div>
  
    <div id="hijo3">
  DivHijo3 <button id="ocul3">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Esta solución refactoriza el código para ahorrar repetir eventos onClick y logica para ocultar el padre.

Se usa un `mutationObserver` sobre el padre que mira el `style` de si mismo y sus hijos.

Cuando uno de los  `div`s se oculta, el observer que lo ha detectado analiza si el padre tiene todos sus div-hijos ocultos. De ser asi, el padre se oculta.

Cuando usamos `hijoX.show()` desde cualquier otra parte del codigo, el observer lo detecta y como ahora no todos sus hijos tienen  `display : none;` entonces, muestra el padre de nuevo.

```js
var padre = $('#padre1');

$("button[id*=ocul").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggle();
});


new MutationObserver(async(records, _) => {
console.clear();
console.log(records[0].target)
  if (padre.find('div[style*="display: none;"]').length == padre.find('div').length) {
    padre.hide();
  } else {
    padre.show();
  }
}).observe(padre[0], {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeFilter: ['style']
});
```

```css
#padre1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre1">
  DivPadre1
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="hijo1">
    DivHijo1 <button id="ocul1">x</button>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo2">
    DivHijo2 <button id="ocul2">x</button>
  </div>

  <div id="hijo3">
    DivHijo3 <button id="ocul3">x</button>
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="$('#hijo1').show()">
mostrar hijo 1 con 'show()'
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con Jquery puedes utilizar una función y comprobar cada vez si el padre se ha quedado sin hijos visibles. Te dejo un ejemplo de como sería:

```js
$("#ocul1").click(function(){
  $("#hijo1").toggle();
  checkEmptyFather();
});


$("#ocul2").click(function(){
  $("#hijo2").toggle();
  checkEmptyFather();
});

$("#ocul3").click(function(){
  $("#hijo3").toggle();
  checkEmptyFather();
});

function checkEmptyFather() {
  if ($("#padre1").children('div :visible').length <= 1){
   $("#padre1").toggle();
  }
}
```

```css
#padre1 {
  background-color:red;
  width:30%;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre1">
  DivPadre1 
    <br>
    <br>
<div id="hijo1">
  DivHijo1 <button id="ocul1">x</button>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo2">
  DivHijo2 <button id="ocul2">x</button>
  </div>
  
    <div id="hijo3">
  DivHijo3 <button id="ocul3">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera, siempre y cuando sepas el numero de hijos que vas a tener.

```js
let nHijos = 3;
let nHijosOcultos = 0;
$("#ocul1").click(function(){
  $("#hijo1").toggle();
  if($("hijo1").is(":visible")){  
   nHijosOcultos--;
  }else{
   nHijosOcultos++;
  }
  eliminapadre();
});


$("#ocul2").click(function(){
  $("#hijo2").toggle();
  if($("hijo2").is(":visible")){
     nHijosOcultos--;
  }else{   
    nHijosOcultos++;
  }
  eliminapadre();
});

$("#ocul3").click(function(){
  $("#hijo3").toggle();
  if($("hijo3").is(":visible")){
   nHijosOcultos--;
  }else{
   nHijosOcultos++;
  }
  eliminapadre();
});

function eliminapadre(){
 if(nHijos == nHijosOcultos){
  $("#padre1").toggle();
 }
}
```

```css
#padre1 {
  background-color:red;
  width:30%;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre1">
  DivPadre1 
    <br>
    <br>
<div id="hijo1">
  DivHijo1 <button id="ocul1">x</button>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo2">
  DivHijo2 <button id="ocul2">x</button>
  </div>
  
    <div id="hijo3">
  DivHijo3 <button id="ocul3">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simplemente he añadido 2 variables que indican el numero de hijos que tiene el `div` padre, y el numero de hijos que están ocultos.

Cuando se oculta un hijo aplico la funcion `.is(":visible")` para saber si el hijo esta oculto. En el caso de estarlo sumaríamos 1 a la variable que cuenta el numero de hijos ocultos, si estuviera visible restaríamos 1.

Cada vez que se oculta pulsa un botón se va a lanzar la función `eliminapadre`, esta comprueba si el numero de hijos y el numero de hijos ocultos es el mismo. En el caso de serlo significaría que todos los hijos están ocultos y por lo tanto el padre también lo estará.

### SOLUCION 2

Comentando por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49211281#49211281) el usuario @lois6b a aportado una solución refactorizada, de manera que ahorramos unas cuantas lineas de código.

```
$("button[id*=ocul").click(function(){
    toggleAndHide($(this).parent())
});

function toggleAndHide(elem){

  elem.toggle()
  if(elem.siblings('div:visible').length  == 0){
    elem.parent().toggle();
  }
}
```

```js
$("button[id*=ocul").click(function(){
  toggleAndHide($(this).parent())
});

function toggleAndHide(elem){

  elem.toggle()
  if(elem.siblings('div:visible').length  == 0){
elem.parent().toggle();
  }
}
```

```css
#padre1 {
  background-color:red;
  width:30%;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre1">
  DivPadre1 
    <br>
    <br>
<div id="hijo1">
  DivHijo1 <button id="ocul1">x</button>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo2">
  DivHijo2 <button id="ocul2">x</button>
  </div>
  
    <div id="hijo3">
  DivHijo3 <button id="ocul3">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con CSS, el selector `:empty` debería funcionar:

```
div#padre:empty { display: none; }
```

Comment: lo intente pero no dio resultado. La idea igualmente sería realizarlo con jquery/javascript

Comment: @Ilsanchez El problema es que realmente no se queda nunca vacío, los hijos están ocultos y hay elementos `<br/>`